# How do I chaining in an exercise?

Tags: sql

the question is : 
The company decided to create an automatic user name, consisting of the first 5 letters (left) of the last name + first letter of the first name, chained. View, Employee Table, Last Name, First Name, and New User Name

my answer:

```
select lastname , FirstName from Employees
select LEFT(lastname,5)as 'lastname',LEFT(firstname,1) as 'firstname' from Employees 

select lastname , FirstName from Employees
select LEFT(lastname,5)as 'lastname',LEFT(firstname,1) as 'firstname' from Employees
```

Comment: What do you mean my "chained"? What is *your* question here?

Comment: @Larnu From the title, I think it's a homework and the question is "help me to answer the exercise and be the greatest one in my class room".

Comment: Use CONCAT ... Select CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(lastname,5), ' ', ''),LEFT(firstname,1)) as 'UserName' from Employees; .

Comment: 1: Are using SQL Server or SQLite? 2: Provide a sample data and the expected results. Thanks

Comment: Why I asked the OP what *their* question was, not what their homework question was, @Sami. :) At least they've shown us their attempt though, which is better than the many "Here is my homework assignment please do it for me" "questions" we see.

Answer (score 0):

```
select LEFT(lastname,5)+LEFT(firstname,1) as Username from Employees
```

that should do what you wanted.
Depending on what SQL-server version you are querying, you can use [concat](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp) as well.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(lastname,5), LEFT(firstname,1))
```